# regex match last character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following lines,

```
data:text/javascript;base64,Ly8gSGVyZdsdsd:5
data:text/javascript;base64,Ly8gSGVyZdsdsd:2
data:text/javascript;base64,Ly8gSGVyZdsdsd:1
```

I want to select the second line of text above using a regex that matches string that ends in `2`? I'm stuck, this is what I have:

```
^.*$
```

Comment: Why just the second line? What is the criteria?

Comment: Maybe: `result = string.match(/^.*2$/m)[0];`

Comment: @user6188402 data:text/javascript;base64,Ly8gSGVyZdsdsd:2

Comment: your question is not explicit enough. why would you want to select second line? because it ends in 2? there lots of guys who already provided a solution for that. you can't select line number in regex. regex parses strings, characters.. \n is just a character...

Answer (score 5):

You can use a very simple pattern

```
string.match(/.*2$/m)
=> ["data:text/javascript;base64,Ly8gSGVyZdsdsd:2"]
```

Where `m` stands for multiline. Without that the `$` will be matched at the end of the string, whereas with this it will match end of *each* line.

Answer (score 2):

`.$`
Short explenation. `.` means any character, or every non-whitespace character, and it should be the last one. This is because of `$` which means it should be the last thing.

Now just implement it in your favoritt language ex. js:

`var string = "hello world!";
Var match = string.match(/.$/);`

(Not sure if match now has the value of "!" Or only a boolean value, js not my strongest language)

Comment: This is only if you need the last character of any of the lines, bot just the one which ends with "2"