# Regex to find last character of string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to validate a string like

AB000A1B

BC222B2P

Conditions :

- String length should be greater than 7
- First two characters must be alphabet
- Characters at index 2,3,4 should be numeric values `// 0 based index`
- Last character of the string should be alphabet (any from B, P, J only)

I've used following code but it can validate only first two character as alphabet and then net 3 characters to be numeric values, how to validate for last character of the string to be any one from B, P, J or how can I achieve the improved pattern for the conditions listed?

```
if (inputString.Length > 7)
{
   string pattern = "^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[B|P|J]$"; 
   Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
   if (rgx.IsMatch(inputString))
   {
    
   }
}
```

Comment: You specify three numeric digits but have `{2}` in your pattern and you don't have anything between them and the last character, e.g. `.*` to match the characters between. Online regex testers like http://regexstorm.net/tester are great for prototyping regex.

Comment: If the string length is 10, and the first 2 characters are alpha, the next 3 are numeric, and the final character is B, P, or J, does that mean the other characters can be anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [regex match last character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338112/regex-match-last-character)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there - except for two minor mistakes.

```
string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}.+[BPJ]$"
```

That should to the trick.  Explanation:

1. `^[a-zA-Z]{2}` - start of the string, followed by two letters
2. `[0-9]{3}` - *three* numeric characters at positions 2,3,4 (not two)
3. `.+` - an arbitrary amount of characters, but *at least* one - you did not specify any limitations for this part. possibly you want to use `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` instead
4. `[BPJ]$` - uppercase letter B, P or J followed by end of the string. in your version, `AB000A1|` would have matched, too.

The length requirement is implicitly enforced because of the sizes of the parts: 2 + 3 + *1 or more* + 1 = 7 or more.

### Edit

I misread the "greater than 7" as "at least 7". In that case the pattern must be `@"^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}.{2,}[BPJ]$"`, as Yong Shun pointed out.

Comment: Hi @Franz, anyway your solution is still valid as the regex checking occurs when fulfilling the string length (via `if` statement). Anyway would like to give a "Thumb Up" for providing a solid solution and explanation. =)

Comment: @YongShun well, you already got my upvote for fixing my mistake

Comment: Got it, thanks. +1 for the explanation so that relevant cases can be understood.

Answer (score 2):

As an extension of @Franz's answer

To enforce your input text must fulfill these requirements:

- First 2 characters must be alphabetical
- Next 3 characters must be numeric
- Last character must be B or P or J
- Input string must be more than 7 characters in length

You can apply the regex below:

```
string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}.{2,}[BPJ]$";
```

`.{2,}` means match **any character with minimum 2 times and above**.

Your regex group will be made up of:

1. Any alphabetic character with length: 2
2. Any numeric character with length: 3
3. Any character with **minimum** length: 2
4. Last character must be either (B or P or J) with length: 1

Plus all these lengths (2 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 8 > 7)

> A valid input must need 8 characters + fulfill the regex group above.

Hence your `if` statement to check the string length must have more than 7 characters is no longer needed.

[Regex & Sample test data](https://regex101.com/r/jnGCsZ/2)